# How to create user paths from clickstream data

Tags: r, clickstream

I have some clickstream data I'd like to attribution analyze in a particular way, but I need to get into a specific format for users that convert and those that don't.

Reprex data:

```
df <- structure(list(User_ID = c(2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2001, 2002, 
                             2001, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2002, 2001), Session_ID = c("1001", 
                                                                                                   "1002", "1003", "1004", "1005", "1006", "1007", "Not Set", "Not Set", 
                                                                                                   "Not Set", "Not Set", "Not Set", "1008", "1009", "Not Set"), 
                 Date_time = structure(c(1540103940, 1540104060, 1540104240, 
                                         1540318080, 1540318680, 1540318859, 1540314360, 1540413060, 
                                         1540413240, 1540538460, 1540538640, 1540629660, 1540755060, 
                                         1540755240, 1540803000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                 Source = c("Facebook", "Facebook", "Facebook", "Google", 
                            "Email", "Google", "Email", "Referral", "Referral", "Facebook", 
                            "Facebook", "Google", "Referral", "Direct", "Direct"), Conversion = c(0, 
                                                                                                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
                                                                                                                                                        "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -15L), spec = structure(list(
                                                                                                                                                          cols = list(User_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                            "collector")), Session_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "collector")), Date_time = structure(list(format = ""), class = c("collector_datetime", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      "collector")), Source = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "collector")), Conversion = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

Then set classes:

```
df <- df %>% 
  mutate(User_ID    = as.factor(User_ID),
         Session_ID = as.factor(Session_ID),
         Date_time  = as.POSIXct(Date_time)
         )
```

I'd like to get all user visit paths to purchase, or total paths for ones that do not lead to purchase.

The format for the new column `path` would be for example: `Facebook > Facebook > Facebook > Email > Email` for user 2001 which I know how to achieve using
`mutate(path = paste0(source, collapse = " > "))`

The complications are:

- The majority of session IDs are not set, meaning they're missing
- Some users may convert more than once
- Some users may convert and return but not convert

Each row would be either:

- A conversion by user ID - most converted users only convert once, but
  some may convert multiple times in which case there would be a row
  per conversion. The `path` column would reflect the journey to
  conversion - for a user's second or subsequent conversion only the
  path subsequent to the previous conversion would be shown.
- Or a non-converted user-journey with their total path in the above format

For the above reprex the result would look like below:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  User_ID Session_ID Date_time           Conversion Path                                          
    <dbl> <chr>      <dttm>                   <dbl> <chr>                                         
1    2001 1007       2018-10-23 17:06:00          1 Facebook > Facebook > Facebook > Email > Email
2    2002 Not Set    2018-10-24 20:34:00          1 Google > Google > Referral > Referral         
3    2003 Not Set    2018-10-26 07:24:00          0 Facebook > Facebook                           
4    2002 1009       2018-10-28 19:34:00          0 Referral > Direct                             
5    2001 Not Set    2018-10-29 08:50:00          1 Google > Direct
```

... where:

- user 2001 converted twice and the paths are represented separately;
- user 2002 converted and then came back later but did not convert and so the converted and non converted paths are represented as separate rows.
- User 2003 never converted and so this path is represented.

Comment: The output is not clear to me. Can you write a sample output that you want to achieve?

Comment: @MFR - quite right - wasn't clear - I've edited the OP and added a resulting data example and explanation. I've also updated the original reprex data to include another use-case.

Comment: Should we use Session_ID (where available) to sort among steps in the path? For User 2001, the time of session 1007 with conversion is prior to the time of session 1005.

Comment: sorry, that's an error - the sessions should be chronologically sequenced.

Comment: so, in answer to your question, with so many session IDs missing I don't know as to it's usefulness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using `dplyr`:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  # Add a column to distinguish between known and unknown sessions
  mutate(known_session = Session_ID != "Not Set") %>%

  # For each user, split between know and unknown sessions...
  group_by(User_ID, known_session) %>%
  # Sort first by Session ID, then time
  arrange(Session_ID, Date_time) %>%
  # Track which # path they're on. Start with path #1; 
  #   new path if prior event was a conversion
  mutate(path_num = cumsum(lag(Conversion, default = 0)) + 1) %>%

  # Label path journey by combining everything so far
  mutate(Path = paste0(Source, collapse = " > ")) %>%
  # Just keep last step in each path
  filter(row_number() == n()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  # Tidying up with just the desired columns, chronological
  select(User_ID, Session_ID, Date_time, Conversion, Path) %>%
  arrange(Date_time)
```

I get slightly different results, but I think they correspond to the sample data as provided:

```
> df2
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  User_ID Session_ID Date_time      

     Conversion Path                                          
  <fct>   <fct>      <dttm>                   <dbl> <chr>                                         
1 2001    1007       2018-10-23 17:06:00          1 Facebook > Facebook > Facebook > Email > Email
2 2002    Not Set    2018-10-24 20:34:00          1 Referral > Referral                           
3 2003    Not Set    2018-10-26 07:24:00          0 Facebook > Facebook                           
4 2002    1009       2018-10-28 19:34:00          0 Google > Google > Referral > Direct           
5 2001    Not Set    2018-10-29 08:50:00          1 Google > Direct
```

Comment: this looks like it works - thanks.